# How to get a public rate card from Azure using REST API if I have a CSP based subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rest-api

I tried using the below API for fetching the rate card:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2016-08-31-preview&%24filter=OfferDurableId+eq+'MS-AZR-0003P'+and+Currency+eq+'USD'+and+Locale+eq+'en-US'+and+RegionInfo+eq+'US'"
```

But I was getting this error:

> The operation is not permitted for namespace Microsoft.Commerce

If anyone could advise on how to fetch a public rate card from Azure using REST API, it would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure, you have registered **Microsoft.Commerce** (Resource provider) on your Subscription.

Follow the below link to register the resource provider:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types